# image fixed content change on single scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

below is my code, I am confuse about write to jquery code, my problem is i want to add class active on next div and remove from the first div on scroll down and same process apply in reverse when i am scrolling up,
please attach your jquery code from the begining

```css
.main {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="content active">
    content 1
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content 2
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://image01.oneplus.net/ebp/201711/10/1712/9350700c52f43348092d34664711c51d.png" class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change position of image fixed to relative.

```
.image{
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: please understand my question than post your comment

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding in a local variable to 3rd function which then updates every time the user scrolls

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
      var currentScreenPosition  = $(document).scrollTop();
      if (currentScreenPosition > divThreeHeight) {
          $( "content" ).addClass( "active" );
      };
   });
});
```